# SharePoint 2013 REST API: how to get or set document fields

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, managed-metadata, rest

I want to get and also set document properties defined in a content type via a Rest call in either and app or a workflow Activity.

If you fire up Google Postman or Advanced REST Api client you can get a desired json response for the query below

```
   http://mydev/sites/test/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Shared Documents/Integration.pdf')/Name
```

.... now I want the more useful fields such as lookups or Managed Metadata values that are also held against my file via a content type.

```
         /CustomerRef
```

seems I need another approach as the the field exists in the view but I am not able to get it in my response . Any ideas how I do this please. 
I have tried ?expand=ContentType

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `ListItemAllFields` as part of the REST URL

```
http://mydev/sites/test/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/test/Shared Documents/Integration.pdf')/ListItemAllFields
```

Comment: Thank you sir!   Yep  I an see all my ct fields. I guess they need to be in the default View to be displayed. Also to pick a single field use /ListItemAllFields/myctfield .... it works!